# Single page application vs Full stack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, database, single-page-application

I am mostly lost in this particular topic.
I want to develop a full stack app with Rails using sqlite 3 as back end now that is good and all, but as a comparison to that full stack app i need to do a single page app. I have no single idea how single pages work? How do you talk to the database, do you use MVVM as a architecture? Were does single page differs from stack? I have a lot of questions if someone could describe in detail what single page app is in reality i would certainly be grateful.

If possible to describe sort of the tools needed for a single page do you need just Angular js and MongoDb and you are good to go? Can you implement ajax? Please I know that it is a total newbie question but i haven't found any real detailed resource about the differences of full stack vs single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails has now an [API only](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html) mode.

For the UI I would use a JavaScript MVC framework such as [React.js](https://www.airpair.com/reactjs/posts/reactjs-a-guide-for-rails-developers) or something like [Angular](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails)

Both links here are for a back-end API built with Rails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no versus between single page and full stack. A single page can consist of multiple stack eg. Front-end, Back-end.

Angular JS is one of the most reputed framework for MVC to create a single Web App. You can use ajax too easily with build in Angular JS service.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into React.js, GraphQL, Relay stack for building single-page apps (used at Facebook). Here is a a nice starter kit which may help you to get started: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit (disclaimer: I'm the author)